# How to add property to object (SimpleXMLElement) using loop (reference)

Tags: php, oop

I have code that retrieves list of data in Object $xmlContent

```
$source = 'http://www.bnm.org/en/official_exchange_rates?get_xml=1&date=23.11.2016';

$xmlString = file_get_contents($source);

$xmlContent = new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
```

How can I add property by reference to the object like we can do this in case of Array?

```
foreach ($xmlContent as $k => &$v) {
    $v['test_property'] = any_function($v->value);
}
```

This code will not work beacuse I can't change and add any values by reference to Object.

How can I add new items to object in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`addChild` function](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) for that:

```
$v; // $v is a SimpleXMLElement object
$v->addChild('nodeName', 'nodeContent');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($xmlContent as $k => $v) {
    $v->addAttribute('test_property', any_function($v->value));
}
```